# SQL Query Multiple Values Of Same Column In One Row

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm trying to get a list of conversations and the participants associated with it in one row along with the last message for a given user. The result I'm looking for is this:

```
**|  conversationId  |  participants  |  text  | timestamp |**
           67           aester,bester    Hello    00:00:00
```

The above model is just one row. I am trying to get all rows with the above result. The text column is the last message associated with that conversation.

Here are my models:

Users

```
userId|username|
   87   aester
   89   cester
   96   bester
```

Conversations

```
|conversationId|
      67
      68
```

Messages

```
| messageId |  text  |  timestamp  |  conversation_id  |  user_id
     41        Hello     00:00:00           67               87
     42        Hey       00:00:00           68               89
```

UserConversations

```
| id | conversation_id | user_id
   3          67            87
   4          67            96
   5          68            89
```

How can I query the above models to get the desired result?

CURRENT UPDATE:

```
SELECT conversations.`conversationId` as conversationId, 
GROUP_CONCAT(users.`username`) as participants FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_conversations 
ON users.`userId` = user_conversations.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN conversations
ON user_conversations.`conversation_id` = 
conversations.`conversationId`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_conversations WHERE 
user_conversations.user_id = 87)
GROUP BY conversations.`conversationId`;
```

The above is producing this which is what I want except I cant figure out how to get the last messages in each row also:

```
|  conversationId  |  participants  |
         67           aester,bester
         68              cester
```

Comment: check [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: I tried using GROUP_CONCAT but it is returning all the participants on the same row even if they don't belong to the conversation

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The databse schema is above. Im going to update the question with what I have so far.

Comment: @xQbert The result at the bottom is correct. Now I just need to get the last message and its timestamp

Comment: We need current data and expected output.

Comment: The current query and expected output is already in the question. I got it to work except for the last message and its timestamp. Thats the hard part right now.

Comment: But where is the current data? Also looks like you are only interested in conversation for `user_id = 87` and that isnt in anywhere in the question. But without the original data I dont know how generated your desire output.

Comment: user_id = 87 is just an example id. Im trying to get all the conversations associated with a given user. Can you please explain what you mean by current data?

Comment: You post your table schema, but didn't include any data. Is like you show me a cake, tell me how you baked but didn't show me the ingredients and expect I get the same result. I could try to guess. But you know what happen then? You can get it wrong and waste your time.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Just updated the data.

Comment: Can I assume the bigger Id for the conversation is the last message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a list of conversation then first we start with `UserConversations` to get the list of participants for each `conversation_id`

```
SELECT uc.`conversation_id`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(u.`username`)  as participants      
FROM UserConversations1 uc
JOIN Users1 u
  ON uc.`user_id`= u.`userId` 
GROUP BY `conversation_id`  
HAVING COUNT(IF(uc.`user_id` = 87, 1, NULL)) > 0; 
    -- This check if the user in on the conversation.
```

Then we found what was the last message for each `conversation_id`

```
SELECT `conversation_id` , MAX(`messageId`) as `messageId`
FROM Messages1
GROUP BY `conversation_id`;
```

Then we join everything together:

[**SQL DEMO**](http://rextester.com/YZBX9595)

```
SELECT conversation.`conversation_id`,
       conversation.`participants`,
       m.text,
       m.timestamp
FROM (  SELECT uc.`conversation_id`,
               GROUP_CONCAT(u.`username`)  as `participants`      
        FROM UserConversations1 uc
        JOIN Users1 u
          ON uc.`user_id`= u.`userId` 
        GROUP BY `conversation_id`  
        HAVING COUNT(IF(uc.`user_id` = 87, 1, NULL)) > 0) as conversation
JOIN ( SELECT `conversation_id` , MAX(`messageId`) as `messageId`
       FROM Messages1
       GROUP BY `conversation_id`) as last_message
  ON conversation.`conversation_id` = last_message.`conversation_id` 
JOIN Messages1 m
  ON m.`messageId` = last_message.`messageId`;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

*NOTE: I have to add `1` to table names because some tables were already on the plataform where I did the demo, and couldnt drop it.*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to join your existing query with Messages table in such a way that you get the last message for each conversation. This can be done like this.

First create a subquery to get last message for each conversation like this

```
select message_id as last_message_id, text as last_text, conversation_id, user_id, max(timestamp) from         
(select * from `Messages`
order by conversation_id, timestamp desc)q
group by conversation_id;
```

Now join the above subquery with your query using conversation_id column as join condition. This will populate last message against your result

Your final query will look like this

```
SELECT conversations.`conversationId` as conversationId, 
GROUP_CONCAT(users.`username`) as participants FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_conversations 
ON users.`userId` = user_conversations.`user_id`
LEFT JOIN conversations
ON user_conversations.`conversation_id` = 
conversations.`conversationId`
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_conversations WHERE 
user_conversations.user_id = 87)
LEFT JOIN 
(select message_id as last_message_id, text as last_text, conversation_id, user_id, max(timestamp) from         
(select * from `Messages`
order by conversation_id, timestamp desc)q
group by conversation_id) subquery
on conversations.`conversationId` = subquery.`conversation_id`
GROUP BY conversations.`conversationId`;
```